# Copy grand total cell of a pivot table to another cell in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I need to build a small 'Balance' sheet in google spreadsheet merging two pivot tables side by side - Incomes and Expenses - and then compute in one single cell the subtraction of expenses from incomes.

The problem is that the grand total cells in pivot tables are not in a fixed cell, as they shift down when rows are added. This mess up my incomes-expenses formula.

I'm searching a way to reference the grand totals cells as they move, or to copy them in fixed cells to allow me to reference with a standard formula.

any idea on how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a late response. However, I was faced with the same problem and from the views of this question it seems like a lot of others have tried to find the answer too.

There is an easy way to reference grand total from the pivot tables into a single cell. I did this using `=getpivotdata("source data field for grand total", pivot-table-reference)`.

For e.g., if the count of *Items Sold* is the grand total value I am looking to copy into a new cell, I'd just type in the cell `=getpivotdata("Items Sold", $A$3)` assuming the $A$3 is the cell of the first column and row of the pivot table.

If you are still stuck on solving this, just type `=` in the cell and click on the grand total cell from the pivot table. You will be able to see the formula and reference the grand total.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with a workaround:

- I've hidden the grand total row in both the pivot tables
- I've cloned the two pivot side by side with ARRAYFORMULA on a new sheet
- I've inserted an empty row on top of this new sheet
- I've manually calculated the grand totals on this empty row with a simple =SUM(A2:A999) formula

This way, the grand total doesn't not float anymore and stay fixed up. I was then able to calculate the substraction.

Comment: answer from Sowmya Shankar below is much better solution.

Comment: better late than never :) I agree, btw